# Could not find SDK SQLite.WP80 Xamarin and Azure build error

Tags: sqlite, azure, windows-phone-8, xamarin

I am building an Azure app with Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2015. My app is happily using both "Azure Mobile Services SQLiteStore" and "Windows Azure Mobile Services" in the Android and iOS builds. However, I am trying to get the same to build and run on WinPhone with little luck. I have tried various things, but typically end up with the following error:

> Could not find SDK "SQLite.WP80, version=3.8.7.2".  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1886
>   5   MyApp.WinPhone

Does anybody have a reliable set of instructions for getting Azure Mobile Services SQLiteStore operational on WinPhone 8.0 ?

Comment: need to install https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a its an extension and needs to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had 2 problems

1. The reference to the `SQLite for Windows Phone` was missed in the WindowPhone App
2. As **InitLipton** said it's necessary to install `SQLite for Windows Runtime` depended on the windows phone version you are using (In my case was [WP Runtime 8](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd120b42-30f4-446e-8287-45387a4f40b7))

here are links of the runtime SDKs

- [WP Runtime 8](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd120b42-30f4-446e-8287-45387a4f40b7)
- [Windows Runtime 8.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a)